# react, как сделать что бы при каждом изменении проект перезагружался?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Есть большой react проект, и там при внесении изменения не перезагружается проект, и даже если перезагрузить страницу изменение не отобразиться, как сделать что бы при каждом изменении, оно сразу же применялось? Используется CRA. Буду благодарен. Может какие-то настройки в .env?

Comment: используйте для этого специальный инструмент **nodemon**

Comment: ммм, нет, это для перезапуска конкретного файла, а в CRA это должно быть по умолчанию, там своя конфигурация webpack.

Comment: нет, в области видимости все файлы проекта, а не конкретный.

Comment: дела не в этом, если использовать nodemon, не получится запустить cra, так как там своя конфигурация.

Comment: мы начинали проект с CRA, проблем работы с nodemon нет. А вы пробовали?

Comment: вот так написать: nodemon react-app-rewired start ?

Comment: Попробовал с помощью nodemon react-app-rewired start, просто бесконечная перезагрузка и все. Не работает.